# Regex create link from word but not if the word contains three dots

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this function which create links around words. It works as intended. However, I would like to exclude words that contain three dots (they are truncated) because they generate invalid links.

```
function renderLinks(data) {
  //Add href to all links
  data = data.replace(/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/g, function(url) {
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
  });
}
```

So if the string is something like: `This is http://stackoverflow.com and it's great!` it should render as `This is <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com"</a> and it's great!`.

If the string is `This is http://stackoverflow.co...` it should not create a link but just skip the word altogether.

I tried with something like:

```
/(?!.*?\.\.\.)(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/g
```

But it's not working.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: These three dots can be anywhere in the document or just on the last and how many consecutive dots there will be?

Comment: I think you should provide more input cases and  expected results for those cases.

Comment: 2 or 3 char for TLD is **really short**, have a look at [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a different regex that doesn't matches the URL that contains three dots at the end.

```js
function renderLinks(data) {
  const regex = /(http|https|ftp|ftps):\/{2}[^\s]+[a-z]{2,3}(?=\s|$)/g;
  return data.replace(regex, function(url) {
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
  });
}

const str1 = "This is http://stackoverflow.com";
const str2 = "This is http://stackoverflow.com and it's great!, we have http://stackoverflow.com again."
const str3 = "This is http://stackoverflow.co...";
const str4 = "This is http://stackoverflow.com and it's great!, we have http://stackoverflow.com again. this is also http://stackoverflow.co... but it won't be converted in to a link";

console.log(renderLinks(str1));
console.log(renderLinks(str2));
console.log(renderLinks(str3));
console.log(renderLinks(str4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm thinking that this check should be done on `url` inside the `replace` callback, since it does not matter if there are `...` in the data, just if it happens to be in the URL

Comment: The three dots are always at the end of the string if it's too long, but there can be multiple words inside the string that sould be converted into links. Hence, excluding words by this check won't work, I think. The check should be made for each word that could possibiy be a link.

Comment: There was a small bug in the code i posted. Use the updated regex.

Comment: FYI `[A-z]` matches more than just letters. Have a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

`[A-z]` matches `[`, <code>\ </code>, `]`, `^`, `_`, <code>`</code>, and the English letters.

Comment: @Toto you are right, thank you for pointing this out. I actually meant to write `[a-z]`.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider filtering, sorting and split/join

```js
const re = /(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?:[^\s]+)/gm

let text = `So if the string is something like: This is http://stackoverflow.com and it's great! 

If the string is This is http://stackoverflow.co... it should not create a link but just skip the word altogether.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756578/regex-create-link-from-word-but-not-if-the-word-contains-three-dots/62756797#62756797 is even better than

But use https://stackoverflow.com/help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756578/regex-create-link-from-word-but-not-if-the-word-contains-three... This is http://stackoverflow.com
This is http://stackoverflow.com and it's great!, we have http://stackoverflow.com again. This is http://stackoverflow.co...
 This is http://stackoverflow.com and it's great!, we have http://stackoverflow.com again. this is also http://stackoverflow.co... but it won't be converted in to a link`

text.match(re).reduce((acc, link) => {
    if (!link.endsWith("...") && !acc.includes(link)) acc.push(link);
    return acc
  }, []) // unique
  .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length) // shortest first
  .forEach(link => text = text.split(link).join(`<a href="${link}">${link}</a>`))
console.log(text)
```

Comment: I did not downvote your answer but i noticed that your code doesn't works for some of the strings i have used in my answer. Some of the links are not replaced with `<a>` element at all and some of them are replaced incorrectly.